# How to load variables from Local Storage using javascript and jquery when creating a form in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small form written in HTML (this is just a sample of what I really am creating in an assignment for class). Basically I have three select tags with options to create a drop down. When the user select a value the total then gets calculated at the bottom of the form. When the user clicks 'save' the data is stored in local storage. Therefore 4 keys are stored in local storage along with the value. I am fine storing A B and C and it's values in local storage but am having issues storing the value of the total. When the user clicks load button it will load the values that was saved in local storage except for the total value.

I added some jquery that will go through all my select and span tags in the html so that it can store that ID and value in local storage.

I hope i made sense. Please copy and paste my code and run it if needed to better understand. I know that my code may not be professional but it's what I have so far and I am still learning. Please let me know what are some things I can do to achieve what I am trying to do. Any small code snippets/examples would be appreciated.

I've tried loading the total value in local storage the same way I was able to load the other values.

```
            <table>
                <tr class="blueHead">
                  <th>Section A.</th>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="blueHead">
                  <td><b>A.1</b></td>
                  <td><b>Value</b></td>
                  <td><b>Awarded</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>a)</td>
                  <td align="center">1</td>
                  <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Aa1">
                                    <option value="0">0</option>
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                  </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>b)</td>
                  <td align="center">1</td>
                  <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Ab1">
                                     <option value="0">0</option>
                                     <option value="1">1</option>
                                     </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>c)</td>
                  <td align="center">2</td>
                  <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Ac1">
                                     <option value="0">0</option>
                                     <option value="2">2</option>
                                     </select></td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="blueHead">
                  <td class="subtotal">Section A. Total</td>
                  <td align="center"><b>2</b></td>
                  <td align="center"><b><div><span id="totalA"></span></div></b></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <button id="save">Save</button>
            <button id="load">Load</button>
            <button value="Refresh Page" onClick="window.location.reload(); localStorage.clear();">Start Over</button>

            <script>
            function calcA1R() {
              var Aa1 = document.getElementById('Aa1');
              var Ab1 = document.getElementById('Ab1');
              var Ac1 = document.getElementById('Ac1');

              var Aa1Val = Aa1.options[Aa1.selectedIndex].value;
              var Ab1Val = Ab1.options[Ab1.selectedIndex].value;
              var Ac1Val = Ac1.options[Ac1.selectedIndex].value;

              // returning the sum of the values
              return [parseInt(Aa1Val), parseInt(Ab1Val), parseInt(Ac1Val)].reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)
            }

            function calcA1() {
              displaySumA()
            }

            function displaySumA() {
              document.getElementById('totalA').textContent = calcSumA()
            }

            function calcSumA() {
              return calcA1R()
            }

            </script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
            <script>

              //Save button
              $('#save').on('click', function(){

                //Iterates through all select fields
                $('select').each(function(){
                    //Set ID for each Select
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    //Set value for each select
                    var value = $(this).val();
                    //adds to localStorage on the broswer
                   localStorage.setItem(id, value);

                });
            });

            $('#load').on('click', function(){
                $('select').each(function(){
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    var value = localStorage.getItem(id);

                    $(this).val(value);

                });
            });
            </script>
```

Comment: Where do you save the total to local storage?

Comment: Why save the total at all? If the sum is just A+B+C, just saving A B and C and adding them when you load is fine.The less localStorage you use, the better IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never actually saving the total in the localStorage. You could save it after your `#save` loop and  retreive it in the `#load` loop. 
 Assuming that your total is the value of the function `calcA1R` :

```js
function calcA1R() {
              var Aa1 = document.getElementById('Aa1');
              var Ab1 = document.getElementById('Ab1');
              var Ac1 = document.getElementById('Ac1');

              var Aa1Val = Aa1.options[Aa1.selectedIndex].value;
              var Ab1Val = Ab1.options[Ab1.selectedIndex].value;
              var Ac1Val = Ac1.options[Ac1.selectedIndex].value;

              // returning the sum of the values
              return [parseInt(Aa1Val), parseInt(Ab1Val), parseInt(Ac1Val)].reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)
            }

            function calcA1() {
              displaySumA()
            }

            function displaySumA() {
              document.getElementById('totalA').textContent = calcSumA()
            }

            function calcSumA() {
              return calcA1R()
            }


              //Save button
              $('#save').on('click', function(){

                //Iterates through all select fields
                $('select').each(function(){
                    //Set ID for each Select
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    //Set value for each select
                    var value = $(this).val();
                    //adds to localStorage on the broswer
                   localStorage.setItem(id, value);

                });
                
                // we save the value of calcA1R
                var total = calcA1R();
                // we are savingthe total into the localstorage with the key "total".
                localStorage.setItem('total', total);
            });

            $('#load').on('click', function(){
                $('select').each(function(){
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    var value = localStorage.getItem(id);

                    $(this).val(value);

                });
                
                var total = localStorage.getItem('total');
                console.log(total);
                // do something with the total here.
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
                <tr class="blueHead">
                  <th>Section A.</th>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="blueHead">
                  <td><b>A.1</b></td>
                  <td><b>Value</b></td>
                  <td><b>Awarded</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>a)</td>
                  <td align="center">1</td>
                  <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Aa1">
                                    <option value="0">0</option>
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                  </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>b)</td>
                  <td align="center">1</td>
                  <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Ab1">
                                     <option value="0">0</option>
                                     <option value="1">1</option>
                                     </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>c)</td>
                  <td align="center">2</td>
                  <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Ac1">
                                     <option value="0">0</option>
                                     <option value="2">2</option>
                                     </select></td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="blueHead">
                  <td class="subtotal">Section A. Total</td>
                  <td align="center"><b>2</b></td>
                  <td align="center"><b><div><span id="totalA"></span></div></b></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <button id="save">Save</button>
            <button id="load">Load</button>
            <button value="Refresh Page" onClick="window.location.reload(); localStorage.clear();">Start Over</button>
```

I've created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2bznxejv/) as well since localstorage is not available in Stackoverflow's embed fiddle creator.

**P.S.** I would highly suggest looking into [ecg8's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8588454/ecg8) comment about localStorage usage. since you are already saving all the data you need to get the total, you can easily calculate back when you retrieve your data.

Comment: Thank you for that, I appreciate it. Well when I refresh the page the total value is gone and when I click load the values A B C are loaded except for the total. That is exactly what I need to be loaded in the form.